# Issue with \emph and unicode-math

Tags: fonts, errors, unicode-math

I have a problem with `\emph` doing nothing when `unicode-math` is used, most likely a fault on my system (up to date vanilla TL2016 on ubuntu) that I cannot find.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
   \textit{this text should be italic} and this one normal.

   \emph{this text should be emphasized} and this one normal.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If I don't load `unicode-math`, the output is as expected:

[image]

Any ideas how to trace this?

Comment: It's an already discussed bug in `fontspec`; a fix is on its way.

Comment: Very sorry for the inconvenience, I know how frustrating this must be!

Comment: @egreg Oh, sorry. Then it's my biological system not up to date. I've been away from TeX world for 6 mo. Case closed. Tx.